# How to call a method inline in ng-include and concatenate the results?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

I would like the results from a method to be part of the string that gets passed to ngInclude.   Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in queryResults.results">
   <div class="box" ng-include="'views/' + getRenderer(result) + 'result.html'"></div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work.  it doesn't throw an error, but the result is `views/result.html`.  I put logging in `getRenderer()` and verified it wasn't being called.

I'm not sure why my code above doesn't work while this code DOES work:

```
<div class="box" ng-include="'views/widgets/' + result.someVariable + 'result.html'"></div>
```

edit:  getRenderer just returns a string:

```
function getRenderer(result) {
    if (result === 'a') {
        return 'aaa';
    else 
        return 'bbb';
}
```

Comment: could you add `getRenderer` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add below to your `controller`. Basically provide an pointer of your function to scope variable so that it could be accessible on HTML

```
$scope.getRenderer = getRenderer
```

Comment: @adapt-dev Glad to help you..Thanks :)